# write a TRANSFORM statement in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, pivot

I am migrating a web application backend from Access to MSSQL, however I was not able o reproduce the following Query in MSSQL, any ideas?

```
TRANSFORM First(FollowUp.FUData) AS FirstOfFUData
SELECT FollowUp.MRN
FROM FollowUp
GROUP BY FollowUp.MRN
PIVOT FollowUp.FU;
```

please note that this query converts data from the EAV table `Followup` to a normal table.
This is the design of the table `Followup`:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function and your query would be set up this way:

```
select MRN, Value1, Value2
from
(
  select MRN, FUData, FU
  from FollowUp
) src
pivot
(
  max(FUData)
  for FU in (Value1, Value2)
) piv
```

Where you would replace the `Value1`, `Value2`, etc with any of the values that you items that should now be columns.

SQL Server 2008, does not have a `FIRST()` function so you will have to use another aggregate function or query the data in such a manner to return the the first record for each item in `FU`.

Another way to write this is using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select MRN, 
  max(case when FU = 'value1' then FUData else null end) Value1,
  max(case when FU = 'value2' then FUData else null end) Value2
from FollowUp
group by MRN
```

The above versions will work great if you have a known number of `FU` values to transform into columns, but if you do not then you will need to use dynamic SQL similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FU) 
                    from FollowUp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT MRN,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select MRN, FUData, FU
                from FollowUp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(FUData)
                for FU in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```