# Transform pivot not working, Incorrect Syntax near 'Sequence'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc, pivot

I'm new in ms access, version is 2005 when i try to test select query its working It display all the column name and its value.

```
$results = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT TOP 5 Sequence
                     ,StoreId
                    ,Timestamp
                    ,BusinessDate
                    ,TerminalId
                    ,TerminalName
                    ,DrawerNumber
                    ,TransactionType
                    FROM [Site5].[dbo].[Transactions] 
                    where [TransactionType] in ('eod','sod') and
                    businessdate = '2016-12-28' ORDER BY  Timestamp asc ");
```

Now I trying to convert the TerminalId Column values into row but its not working here is my code

```
    $transform = odbc_exec($connection, "
        TRANSFORM MAX(Sequence)
        SELECT StoreId
        FROM Transactions
        GROUP BY StoreId
        PIVOT TerminalId 
        ");
```

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0][SQL Server]Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'Sequence'., SQL state 37000

Comment: what's the first query for? just only top 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221593/write-a-transform-statement-in-sql-server

Comment: Its a huge number of files its too long to load that's why I limit to 5

Comment: There is no Access 2005. You may be referring to SQL Server 2005? Please explain your db architecture (ie., frontend, backend, etc). Which RDBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

fully qualified tables

```
$transform = odbc_exec($connection, "
        TRANSFORM MAX(Transactions.Sequence) As Seq  
        SELECT Transactions.StoreId
        FROM Transactions
        GROUP BY Transactions.StoreId
        PIVOT Transactions.TerminalId 
        ");
```

or

```
$transform = odbc_exec($connection, "
        TRANSFORM MAX(Transactions.Sequence) As Seq  
        SELECT Transactions.StoreId
        FROM [Site5].[dbo].Transactions
        GROUP BY Transactions.StoreId
        PIVOT Transactions.TerminalId 
        ");
```

Comment: probably does not like the Alias.. perhaps the second one